# Index match over multiple sheets in excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, macros

*This is my first post, if anything is not in order pleas let me know so I can correct it.*

For a project, I'm building a prototype that reads pipeline component files into excel, extracts the parts and coordinates and displays them in a graph. 
With a macro that gives me the ability to order the parts by clicking in the graph on the coordinates, I sort the parts manually. In this sheet I need to add data like part name and the absolute Z value.
Here is where my problem comes in.

So far I've been able to use a separate INDEX and MATCH function to call my missing information from one of the pipeline datasheets, but when I combine them, the return an error (I've had #N/A; #REF and #VALUE for starters).

**My questions are**;

1. how can I build the INDEX MATCH function to return the name and Z value from one sheet?
2. Is it possible to nest this function to search all sheets in the file to return these values?
3. I use a combination of formulas and visual basics, which one can be used to be more dynamic?

Any help is appreciated :)

**Background info:**
I have at least 4 sheets with pipeline data, 1 sheet with the graph to click on and 1 sheet where the filtered data is placed.

The data from the the graph sheet is called from the datasheets. Then the data in the graph is selected and copied to Sheet3 where the black line is the recall from path, red is data from the graph sheet and blue one source for the grpah (I've used one datafile to start with) (purple/pink, things I've tried). 
Then the required data has to be called from the datasheet, all the datasheets have the same format.

Images
sheet 3

[image: sheet 3]

datasheet

[image: datasheet]

I did find some information about a VLOOKUP across multiple sheets], but I was unable to implement the example in my situation. I've also checked the subReddits Excel and visual basic for information with little success.

Comment: Thoughts on question 2):  well if you have VBA, and you want to check on multiple sheets, just have the VBA loop through the sheets you want to search until you either find something, or you get to the last sheet and still find nothing.  Can the thing you are searching for be found on multiple sheets?  if so you are looking at developing a list!

Comment: FYI, in the future you are better to use the second link on imgur to link your images.  When you have enough rep you use that second link and the insert image tool in your question, and it will move the linked image into SO's account on Imgur so that way you picture in not delete in a couple of months time.

Comment: you say "combine them", what is "them"?  On which of the two images do you sort the parts manually?  ( I am assuming N-557-49..)

Comment: in reference to question 1),  I am having a hard time keeping track of all this, you state "...return the name and Z value from one sheet"  which sheet is the one sheet?  are these the various N-... sheets?

Comment: ok, just going to toss this back at you in my own words to see if I understand this right.  On sheet three you want to find the value of Z based on the name in Column A.  You need it to search through column J on each of the N-....sheets until it finds a match, and use the Z from the corresponding row in Column E.

Comment: and if I got that last bit right, are the part names unique and they only show up once across all your N-...sheet names?

Comment: Some quick notes on you matches.  I noticed you are dong a match type 1 and you are searching based on B2...so you are trying to match X coordinates.in order to do a match with a type 1 search parameter, the field you are searching has to be sorted in ascending order.  if your field you are searching in is unsorted you can only perform a match type 0 which is finding an exact match.  and seeing how many decimal places you are working with, this may or may not be viable due to small rounding errors.

Comment: @ Forward Ed, Thank's for the reply. My VBA is not that on point, but I will start checking out that option becaus VBA. Your understanding of my doing is correct. I'll do that imgur thingy next time tx. With "combine them" I mean to concatnate an INDEX MATCH function instead of just one INDEX and one MATCH function where I later combine the result from the MATCH in the INDEX function. I just realized that my project will not work because the names are only unique to one sheet, but could be duplicates on other sheets. there the cords will be different hmm..

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your data should all be consolidated in one tab. If you're ever trying to execute a lookup across multiple tabs, it probably means you need to structure your data source differently. Whatever criteria that differentiates the different tabs, just make that a new column on the table.

In case you're still wondering about #1, you can just concatenate multiple Index/Match functions together and change the column #.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$8,MATCH($G$3,$A$2:$A$8,0),1)&" - "&INDEX($B$2:$D$8,MATCH($G$3,$A$2:$A$8,0),2)
```

Comment: So If I understand you correctly, avoid the multi tab approach and gather all the Isometric data in one tab and then use the lookup. I will investigate this one and see what kind of results it will bring me. thank you.

Comment: I have found the closer your spreadsheet is to a clean database, the better. The power of Excel is that you can have something like a database table on one tab and then build pretty charts/dashboards on the next tab, all in the same software, and in a fraction of the time. That flexibility and ease of use can lead to sloppiness though (speaking from personal experience with my own spreadsheets).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of u/semicolonsemicolon from the website Reddit. here is the VBA solution to my own problem. For this code to work check my [workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwHhfh35aCakRVN1YmZSTGJaUkE/view) that contains the modules that I've used. For my solution I've used some of john peltiers code on "how to get x andy on your chart". The code in the class module can be swapped for the code below. 
Thank you for taking the time to check my problem.

```
Private Sub EmbChart_MouseUp _
    (ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)

Dim ElementID As Long, Arg1 As Long, Arg2 As Long
Dim myX As Double, myY As Double
Dim rng As Range, t As String

If Button = xlPrimaryButton Then
    With EmbChart
       Call .GetChartElement(X, Y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2) ' call the coordinates that have been clicked

        Application.StatusBar = "[" & ElementID & "]"

         If ElementID = xlSeries Or ElementID = xlDataLabel Then
                If Arg2 > 0 Then
                    myX = WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues, Arg2)
                    myY = WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Values, Arg2)
                    Application.StatusBar = "[" & myX & ", " & myY & "]"
                    Select Case Arg1
                     Case 1: t = "tabbleud"
                     Case 3: t = "tabblad"
                     Case 4: t = "tableeed"
                    End Select
                    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").[B200].End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                          .Value = myX
                          .Offset(0, 1).Value = myY
                          .Offset(0, -1).Value = Evaluate("=INDEX(" & t & "[IDENT name],SUMPRODUCT((" & t & "[X]=" & myX & ")*(" & t & "[Y]=" & myY & ")*(ROW(" & t & "[X])-ROW($A$2)+1)))")
                          .Offset(0, 2).Value = Evaluate("=INDEX(" & t & "[Z],SUMPRODUCT((" & t & "[X]=" & myX & ")*(" & t & "[Y]=" & myY & ")*(ROW(" & t & "[X])-ROW($A$2)+1)))")
                        End With
                End If
        Else
            If TypeName(Selection) = "Nothing" Then
                MsgBox "Chart element " & ElementID _
                    & " (" & Arg1 & ", " & Arg2 & ")."
            ElseIf ElementID = xlShape Then

                'Chart Embedded in Chart Sheet
                MsgBox "Chart element " & ElementID _
                    & " (" & Arg1 & ", " & Arg2 & ")."
            Else
                MsgBox "Chart element " & ElementID _
                    & " (" & Arg1 & ", " & Arg2 & ")."
            End If
        End If

    End With
End If
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```